# How to block facebook for particular time intervals in ubuntu server?

Tags: facebook

How can i  block facebook for particular time intervals in Ubuntu server?

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Pull the cable off? What is it exactly you want to block?

Answer (score 2):

If you like to do it command line:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -d ipaddress_here -m time --timestart 09:00 --timeend 22:00 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -d ipaddress_here -j REJECT
```

Those are two rules for your iptable allow to use port 80 for specificIP in a specific time and reject in other times.

All you have is to replace the ip-address of facebook letus say and put the timestart and timeend

But this is great IF you know the IP's.

For that I provide you other ways:

If you use Google Chrome, I strongly recommend the [StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji) 
extension. It takes a second to install and 30 seconds to configure the options - choose how much time you want to allow yourself to be on Facebook and other sites that you class as time-wasting.

If you're a Firefox user, consider [LeechBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/).